# How to change shell to dash from bash

Tags: bash, shell, dash-shell

I want to execute some scripts on dash shell compared to standard default bash. This is an example (test.sh)

```
#!/bin/dash
echo $SHELL 
echo $0
```

This execution gives me

```
/bin/bash
./test.sh
```

as output. I was expecting '/bin/dash' as output.

If this is wrong, can someone let me know how do I actually work on dash.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate that you are running dash by adding the command

```
ps | grep $$
```

The `$$` variable contains the `PID` of the process of the running shell.

Comment: This worked: dash test.sh with the above command and obtained 'dash' at output confirming the shell.

Answer (score 3):

`SHELL` environment variable picks up the value from `/etc/passwd`.  (It denotes the path to user's preferred command language interpreter.)

This value wouldn't change if you change the shell in your session or your script.

Answer (score 1):

This one would show the exact command.

```
ps o command --no-header --pid "$$"
```